# How to test Laravel Mail sent with string body, not using Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-6

I have this email that goes out

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($email) {
    $message->to($email->to)
        ->subject($email->subject)
        ->setBody($email->content, 'text/html');
});
```

How can I assert that this mail is sent in a test?

Using the `Mail::fake()` facade, but `Mail::assertSent()` wants a string Mailable.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: you can use `mailtrap.io` instead of creating fake. Its come to mail which you provide

Comment: R u using Behat to test? If yes I might post my test here. I'm using Mailtrap API to check if an email message can be found at Mailtrap Inbox.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a `Mailable` class? That makes it very easy to assert. And it makes your dev life a lot easier ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default, PHPUnit is using `array` mail driver and stores all sent mail in an array.

So one option is to ditch `Mail::fake()`, fire the email in test, and then inspect the array of messages.

A custom assertion that I use in my tests:

```
protected function assertMailSentTo($user, $times = 1)
{
    // resolves the mail driver and gets messages
    $messages = app('swift.transport')->messages();

    $filtered = $messages->filter(function ($message) use ($user) {
        return array_key_exists($user->email, $message->getTo());
    });

    $expected = $times;

    $actual = $filtered->count();

    $this->assertTrue(
        $expected === $actual,
        "Sent {$actual} messages instead of {$expected}."
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mail::send returns a value.
Try assigning this to a variable and check the value; should be true (if the mail is sent) or false (if it is not sent). 
Also, you could use a site like Mailinator to create a temporary ID to receive mails.

Answer (score 0):

I asked this same question some months ago, and I decided to test if a message was *received*.

Maybe it disobeys the "[Don't Mock What You Don't Own](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don't-mock-what-you-don't-own)" rule, but as it is working for me, I decided to keep it.

I don't know if you are using [Behat](https://behat.org/en/latest/) as I am, but I hope it may help someone. I'm also using [MailTrap API](https://mailtrap.docs.apiary.io/#) here. Here it is for what's worth.

Well, once you are using Behat, at your `FeatureContext.php` create a function like this:

```
/**
 * @Given I received a password reset token link at inbox
 */
public function iReceivedAPasswordResetTokenLinkAtInbox()
{
    $inbox = env('MAILTRAP_INBOX');
    $mailTrapToken = env('MAILTRAP_TOKEN');

    $options = [
        'headers' => [
            'Api-Token' => $mailTrapToken              
        ]            
    ];

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client($options);
    $apiMailTrap = 'https://mailtrap.io/api/v1';

    $response = $client->request('GET', "{$apiMailTrap}/inboxes/{$inbox}/messages");

    $msg = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    $response = $client->request('GET', "{$apiMailTrap}/inboxes/{$inbox}/".
        "messages/{$msg[0]->id}/body.txt");

    // Here you can get the message body and make any verification you need
    $bodyTxt = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    // In my case, I had to check if a URL was successfully sent, so        
    $this->tokenPasswordReset = trim(substr($bodyTxt, strpos($bodyTxt,'/resetpassword/') + 15, 60));         

    print('token: '.$this->tokenPasswordReset);

    // Then I made my assertion
    PHPUnit::assertNotEmpty($this->tokenPasswordReset);
}
```

In my case, once I had the function above, in order to test an endpoint, I simply added a file called `resetpw.feature` containing:

```
Feature: Changing Password
In order to reset an user password
As an user
I want to reset my password and update it

@password
Scenario: Users want to reset their passwords
Given I send a POST request to "/resetpassword" with parameters:
| key        | value                    |
| email      | behat@mytests.dev        |
Then the response status code should be 200

Given I received a password reset token link at inbox
# And here comes the previously created function!

When I access a password reset link with this token
Then the response status code should be 200
```

Then I run `behat --tags @password` to test.

That's it. I hope it may inspire someone!